# Get selected optgroup in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the below `select` tag with two `optgroup`.

```
<select id="linkSelector" class="form-control" onchange="linkDropDown();">
  <optgroup label="Input">
   <option value="default">Road type</option>
   <option value="lanes">Lanes</option>
   <option value="length">Length</option>
   <option value="speed">Speed</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="Ouput">
   <option value="congestion">Congestion</option>
   <option value="speed_output">Speed</option>
   <option value="travel_time">Travel Time</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I would like to execute `myFuncton()` depending on the selected `optgroup`.
For example if one of the dropdown value belong to `<optgroup label="Input">`, then execute `myFunction()`.

I tried this:

```
var linkSelector = document.getElementById('linkSelector')
opt = linkSelector.getElementsByTagName('optgroup')
if (opt[0].label =='Input'){
    myFunction()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go about this, would be to get the selected option for the select field, then find out it's parent's label.

```
var label = document.getElementById('linkSelector').selectedOptions[0].parentElement.label;
if (label === "Input") {
  myFunction();
}
```

Comment: Lots of thanks, It 's working